# How to decode unicode raw literals to readable string?

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, unicode-literals

If I assign unicode raw literals to a variable, I can read its value:

```
>>> s =  u'\u0421\u043e\u043e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043e'
>>> s
u'\u0421\u043e\u043e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043e'
>>> print s
Сообщение отправлено
```

But when I have already assigned value to a plain, not unicode string, I can not:

```
>>> s =  '\u0421\u043e\u043e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043e'
>>> s
'\\u0421\\u043e\\u043e\\u0431\\u0449\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435 \\u043e\\u0442\\u043f\\u0440\\u0430\\u0432\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u043e'
>>> print s
\u0421\u043e\u043e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043e
```

How can I decode and read it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the [unicode_escape codec](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html):

```
s.decode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: (The reason is that '\uXXXX' is *verbatim* in a non-Unicode string literal.)

Comment: Found the best solution ever specially for Russian Characters

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting weird results when decoding try following

```
print repr(s).decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1') // or encode using some other encoding
```

It could be that python terminal is using default ASCII and there is symbol that goes out of range.